# $this->input->post() not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

Here is my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo lang('email'); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('email') ? set_value('email') : $profile['email']; ?>">
```

When I submit form then controller process data like

```
$user = array(
            'email' => trim($this->input->post('email', TRUE)),
            'username' => trim($this->input->post('username', TRUE)),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE)),
            'email' => trim($this->input->post('mobile', TRUE))
   );
```

Now `var_dump(trim($this->input->post('email', TRUE)));return;` This output as (var_dump() result)

```
string 'rejoan.er@gmail.com' (length=19)
```

But array is not working for SAME FORM with SAME DATA. When `var_dump($user)` Then `email` field data not receiving. It shows as following

```
array (size=3)
  'email' => string '' (length=0)
  'username' => string 'rejoan' (length=6)
  'password' => string 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' (length=32)
```

What I did wrong here???

Comment: check your form for typos or dump $_POST

Comment: @peter yes double checked. It ok as single `var_dump(trim($this->input->post('email', TRUE)));return;` is working fine

Comment: You have 2 `email` from 2 input inside your `$user` array. Have you removing the latest? and can you `var_dump($this->input)` ?

Comment: Different set of eyes help @RejoanulAlam. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor error on that

```
$user = array(
    'email' => trim($this->input->post('email', TRUE)),
    'username' => trim($this->input->post('username', TRUE)),
    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE)),
    'email' => trim($this->input->post('mobile', TRUE)) <==== Error is in here
);
```

**Change second `'email'` to `'mobile'`**